# Please tell me how to get zclip work

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

can anyone provide me a example of a jQuery Zclip. http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/

I tried the demo they have given. but seems i cant get it to work. Thanks.

Comment: It seems to work for me... make sure you have flash enabled.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work for me.

Make sure you have the version of flash that it says on the site **and** that it is enabled.

Comment: flash its working. and i can copy when i click it in there site. when i copy the code and try it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: @zack... do you have all the code -- including the flash? (usually an swf file)